# Creating a Nuget Package with Nuget Pack Says to Add a dependency group for net6.0 to the nuspec and Dots Required?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

When creating a nuget package from a c# .net 6 class library with nuget.exe, I first run "nuget spec" to generate a nuspec file. Then when attempting to create a nuget package .nupkg by running "nuget pack" the output says:

> "Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the
> nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other
> location. Consult the list of actions below:
> Add a dependency group for net6.0 to the nuspec"
>
> The following packaged file folder(s) require(s) dots in the framework version: lib/net60/myLibrary.dll

This is a clean .net 6 class library, and nuget.exe is version 6.0.

Why does it think I have anything in the dependencies group of the nuspec and lib/ref folder not matching the "other location?" I don't even have a dependencies group in the nuspec.

I seem to have placed dots in the target framework stated in my csproj, why is it complaining that my framework specifier is missing dots?

**My csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>myLibrary</PackageId>
    <Author>me</Author>
    <Company>myCompany</Company>
    <Description>Library defining common objects</Description>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**My nuspec:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <!-- <icon>icon.png</icon> -->
    <projectUrl>http://project_url_here_or_delete_this_line/</projectUrl>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Why do you need a nuspec? I can perfectly run `dotnet pack` just like that. [Here's my Github workflow](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-master.yml)

Comment: @Pieterjan I'd rather not use nuspec, and was actually trying to troubleshoot dotnet pack because it didn't seem to work. After running dotnet pack I was expecting a .nupkg output but dotnet pack is outputting a .nuspec. It then seemed I needed to run nuget pack against the .nuspec to get anything to happen.

Are you getting a .nuget output of dotnet pack for a class library targeting .net6.0? 

Trying to add the dotnet pack's output nuspec to another project via "dotnet add package myLibrary --version 1.0.0" always says "error: There are no versions available for the package 'myLibrary'"

Comment: @Pieterjan - okay I was just an idiot with the dotnet pack - and didn't look in bin after I saw the nuspec created in obj. 

So dotnet pack generates a .nupkg fine - and now back to trying to figure out why adding it to another project always says "error: There are no versions available for the package 'myLibrary'."

Comment: What's the output of the command `dotnet nuget list source`? Is your package published to any of these sources? You can also add a source with a local folder reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was dumb - but here's what I fixed in case anyone made the same mistake I made.

1.) Dotnet Pack will output a **nupkg** into bin, and a **nuspec** into obj. I didn't realize there was a difference, and have tried before to use the nuspec, but the nupkg in bin (not nuspec in obj) is what installs correctly.

2.) I was trying to use nuget.exe's "nuget pack" command instead of the "dotnet pack" command when I kept getting  "error: There are no versions available for the package 'myLibrary'." when adding the output to another project.

3.) I had thought maybe "dotnet pack" was not working, as I saw it outputting a nuspec file instead of a nupkg. This was a misunderstanding, as it outputs both. The nupkg is found in the bin folder, the nuspec shows up in obj.

4.) I made a mistake in my csproj property group by not including a "version" tag like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>myLibrary</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Author>me</Author>
    <Company>myCompany</Company>
    <Description>Library defining common objects</Description>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Thought about deleting this sad question, but will leave it in case anyone else makes the same string of incorrect assumptions and errors that I made.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the warning 'NU5128: - Add a dependency group for net6.0 to the nuspec' was shown even with 'dotnet pack' ; it was due in fact to the `<SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>true</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>` element in the csproj. (ASP.NET Core, Razor Class Library)